# Fixed element positioning on Shopify

Tags: html, css, shopify

My problem is here: https://paper-boy-posse-2.myshopify.com/

I have tried and tried again but haven't been able to make my marquee (the orange and grey banner which is a fixed element) centered or responsive. As you can see when you reduce the screen size it no longer covers the top of the carousel and instead shifts to the right. When it is normal screen size, it isn't even centred.

So my question is. How can i make this fixed element:
- Centered
- Responsive (so it stays covering the top of the carousel)

My code is below.

```
<!-- Begin right navigation -->
  {% if settings.navigation_alignment == "right" %}
  <div class="row" id="header">
    <div class="span12 border-bottom">
      <div class="span12" style="margin-top:50px;">
            <div class="logo">
                <img src="http://img69.imageshack.us/img69/4620/gcl6.png"/>
            </div>
      </div> 
    </div>
  </div>


  {% endif %}
  <!-- End right navigation -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the position of the banner and resize it to cover the carousel then use media queries.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {



}
```

and in between give modify the image as needed, read up on media queries to have a better understanding!